# Failed to get a remote user to authenticate successfully with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I installed RabbitMQ 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 14.04, and I'd like to make a basic producer-consumer example with pika, but unlike the tutorials on RabbitMQ's website, I'd like the consumer to be on another machine.

I know that I can add `[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].` to rabbitmq.config and avoid all authentication issues, but I'd like to include the authentication aspect of the connection in my example.

I started by adding a new user: `rabbitmqctl add_user user password`, and then I ran the following script:

```
import pika

url = '10.0.0.1'

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=url, credentials=credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
connection.close()
print 'Made it through!'
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 410, in _flush_output
    self._impl.ioloop.poll()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 602, in poll
    self._process_fd_events(fd_event_map, write_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 443, in _process_fd_events
    handler(fileno, events, write_only=write_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 364, in _handle_events
    self._handle_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 407, in _handle_read
    return self._handle_error(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 338, in _handle_error
    self._handle_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 288, in _handle_disconnect
    self._adapter_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 95, in _adapter_disconnect
    super(SelectConnection, self)._adapter_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 154, in _adapter_disconnect
    self._check_state_on_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 178, in _check_state_on_disconnect
    raise exceptions.ProbableAccessDeniedError
pika.exceptions.ProbableAccessDeniedError
```

According to pika's source, this means: "Client was disconnected at a connection stage indicating a probable denial of access to the specified virtual host", so I thought maybe I should add a vhost instead of using the default one, so I ran `rabbitmqctl add_vhost testvhost`, restarted the server, and ran the following script:

```
import pika

url = '10.0.0.1'
vhost = 'testhvost'

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=url, virtual_host=vhost, credentials=credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
connection.close()
print 'Made it through!'
```

However I still get the same exception.

What am I missing? Is there any basic rabbitmq.config file I need to have before I can get this to work? The server is a clean installation, so no config file is loaded at the moment.

Comment: Does your server setup require connections use SSL?

Comment: @MattS Not as far as I know, it's just two clean Ubuntu VM which are connected to the same virtual network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the permissions to that user to access the virtual host?

To the default virtual host:

`rabbitmqctl set_permissions user ".*" ".*" ".*"`

And to your newly created:

`rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /testhvost user ".*" ".*" ".*"`